# use greater than operand in angularjs controller

Tags: html, angularjs, scope, operand

Data in my controller

```
$scope.data = [{
                "F": "1,26,000"
            }];

$scope.data2 = [{
                "F": "26,000"
            }];
```

this is my data in my controller now i want to use if else condition here

```
if (Number($scope.data[0].F) > Number($scope.data2[0].F))
   {
      console.log('aaa');
   }
else {
      console.log('bbb');
     }
```

now if data is greater then data2 `('aaa')` should print and of it is less then `('bbb')` should print

Now as you see data is greater then data2

`('aaa')` this should be printed on my console but instead of that `('bbb')` this is printing in console,

what i need to change in my controller??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commas so it's `"126000"` and `"26000"`

Can also do

```
if (parseInt($scope.data[0].F) > parseInt($scope.data2[0].F))
   {
      console.log('aaa');
   }
else {
      console.log('bbb');
     }
```

`parseInt` converts the string to a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
var f =parseFloat(($scope.data[0].F).replace(/,/g, ''));

var f2 =parseFloat(($scope.data2[0].F).replace(/,/g, ''));

  if ( f>f2){
      console.log('aa');
   }
else {
      console.log('bbb');
     }
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this answers the question?